# How to Display DataTable as output in rest service in XML FORMAT

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

How to Display Data Table as output in rest service in XML FORMAT

Answer (score 2):

`DataTable` has a method `WriteXml` that contains many overloaded versions. One of them is `DataTable.WriteXml(string)`. You can use this to save the contents of `DataTable` as an XML file. The other option you can use is the overloaded method that writes to `Stream` object. You can use either `FileStream`, `MemoryStream` or similar.

Any of the overloaded methods contains a version with `XmlWriterMode` argument that allows you to specify whether you want to write schema or ignore it.